# Is Multicommodity Flow problem really NP-hard?

Tags: network-flow

Within paper `ON THE COMPLEXITY OF TIMETABLE AND MULTI-COMMODITY FLOW PROBLEMS`

there's a proof that the multi-commodity is NP-hard.

While in `Multicommodity flows over time: Efficient algorithms and complexity`

authors states that "[...] the only known polynomial-time algorithms for static multicommodity flow computations require general linear programming techniques".

They use word "static" only to differ from its time-dependent version. But I think it is the same problem considered in the first paper.
Authors also refer to its complexity with the wording "poly($\simeq$LP)".

Can someone help me understand the right way of reading this apparent contradiction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"ON THE COMPLEXITY OF TIMETABLE AND MULTI-COMMODITY FLOW PROBLEMS" talks about integral flow while "Multicommodity flows over time: Efficient algorithms and complexity" does not. The integrality constraint (flows being integer valued) is important see LP vs ILP.